# Joomla ACL and alternative page content

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, acl, joomla-extensions

We have a site where we are intending to sell access to video tutorials. I have set up Joomla ACL to limit access to those pages only to those users who have been given the relevant access permissions and access is being sold through shopping cart called MijoShop.

This setup is working okay at the moment, but there is bit of an issue with user experience. At the moment it seems I can only stop people from viewing a page, but I can't see an easy way to show them alternative content with Joomla ACL. Ideally, if a logged-in user does not have access to a certain video tutorial page, when they click on the link to the page they will instead see a page giving them an opportunity to buy access to the tutorial. This means that I need a method for showing different content on the same page depending on which Joomla user groups a user is assigned to. Is this possible with vanilla Joomla ACL, or am I going to have to find a content management extension that can add the ability to do this?

Comment: How are you setting up the ACL structure. If you add in a simple if/else command on the page itself (rather than assigning the menu item to have a permission level) this should be realatively straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. That may be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with the Vanilla ACL.  IIRC you can setup various groups with access to different tutorials/pages/things - then you can make a member a part of multiple groups - thus giving them access to those things as needed.

If unable to do something like that - then I think George Wilsons comment would suffice for a while and you could implement some if/then/else type statements into the code of the article which would work.

Your best bet however is to try the ACL solution first and foremost as that allows you to keep things generally more easy to manage from a backend perspective.

Comment: The problem is that if a user doesn't have access to a menu link then they don't have access to the page at all. If they do have access to the menu, but not to the article assigned to the link then the page appears blank. It's these blank pages I want to replace with alternative content. I know that I can give them access to an alternative set of articles, but what I need is to be able to show alternative content on a page if they try to access pages they don't have rights to.

Maybe a PHP if/else or a plugin which allows alternative page content based on login rights are the only options.

Comment: You're probably right.  I see what you're saying a little more clearly now and I think the good idea is to find a plugin, or simply write a simple if/else.  I would prefer the way of writing an if/else and using Sourcerer (great tool!) to write the PHP directly into the article.  Then just save that somewhere local and copy/paste into any article.  I find having an article template in place for sites I routinely post on is uber helpful too, then it's simply 'copy/paste/replace' making it much easier to manage.  I wish I had more ideas but it seems like you have a handle on it!  Good luck!